# PHP preg_match subpattern captures too much text (too greedy)

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I'm using preg_match to match the first contact page link within some HTML markup.

I have spent many hours investigating, reading PHP regex documents, debugging, and trying to find a similar solution on StackOverflow. There is a lot of advice for regex, just could not find it specific to my subpattern issue.

Example HTML:-

```
<ul class='root dropdown'><li class="item1 current-item-root first-item current-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li><li class="item2"><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li><li class="item3 parent category-page"><a
```

Instead of returning

```
/contact-us
```

it returns

```
"/">Home</a></li><li class="item2"><a href="/contact-us
```

Here is the code:-

```
preg_match( '/href.{1,5}"(?P<link>.{0,50}contact.{0,20})"/isxU', $input_line, $output_array);
```

I expected the regex U setting to make {0,50} non-greedy, but it's grabbing too much text.

The code is designed to pick up href links in various formats like below:-

```
/contact
/contact-us
websitename.com/contact-me
```

Here is a working example:-
https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/Dh2

Comment: Maybe `href=".*?\K(/?contact[^"]+)"` but need to define what you expect to allow, absolute, relative, both? Also, a parser would be better, this would match more than just links.

Comment: Thank you for replying and the idea, no success yet. I've started to investigate making a better match outside of the  subpattern. What I would like to know is why my subpattern grabs so much text and doesn't match the double quote around the href link. It works if I reduce {0,50} to {0,20) for example, but that is it needs to be bigger to fit all cases.

Comment: It works for defined use case. Maybe add some more use cases/examples. Here's demo https://regex101.com/r/sxpj4I/1

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help. The answer was to exclude any other quotes captured in the sub-pattern, which was part of your example. The best and most fantastic part of your answer was to direct me to use https://regex101.com/ . That's an amazing tool for regex, great highlighting and explanations of the expression.

My answer:-

```
href="(?<link>[^"]{0,50}contact.*[^"]{0,50})"
```